# is it possible to add a button with variable in templatetags

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates

templatetags.py

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.filter("as_span")

def as_span(ZergitForm):
    ZergitForm_as_span = ZergitForm.as_ul().replace("<ul", "<span").replace("</ul", "</span")
    ZergitForm_as_span = ZergitForm_as_span.replace("<li", "<span").replace("</li", "</span")
    return mark_safe(ZergitForm_as_span)
```

I am using MultipleChoiceField.After using this templatetag it is printing the form data in a span instead of `<li>` tag.I want to do an delete operation for each data inside the span.Now it is printing each `<li>` value in individual `<span>` tag.I need to insert a input button for each span.

Is it possible to do using templatetag concept.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar when rendering the field instead of the whole form.

If you build a templatetag to render a field you can use its id which you need to adress an ajax-call to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off replacing those fields' widget. It seems like you are using a `CheckboxSelectMultiple`, which uses `<ul>` and `<li>`. Create a class that descends from `CheckboxSelectMultiple` and replace its `render()` method:

(from django/forms/widgets.py)

```
class CheckboxSelectMultiple(SelectMultiple):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
        if value is None: value = []
        has_id = attrs and 'id' in attrs
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
        output = [u'<ul>']
        # Normalize to strings
        str_values = set([force_unicode(v) for v in value])
        for i, (option_value, option_label) in enumerate(chain(self.choices, choices)):
            # If an ID attribute was given, add a numeric index as a suffix,
            # so that the checkboxes don't all have the same ID attribute.
            if has_id:
                final_attrs = dict(final_attrs, id='%s_%s' % (attrs['id'], i))
                label_for = u' for="%s"' % final_attrs['id']
            else:
                label_for = ''

            cb = CheckboxInput(final_attrs, check_test=lambda value: value in str_values)
            option_value = force_unicode(option_value)
            rendered_cb = cb.render(name, option_value)
            option_label = conditional_escape(force_unicode(option_label))
            output.append(u'<li><label%s>%s %s</label></li>' % (label_for, rendered_cb, option_label))
        output.append(u'</ul>')
        return mark_safe(u'\n'.join(output))
```